# how to populate each section row of uitableview dynamically from json

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have more than one section and i want to populate each section rows dynamically. [image: to get some idea see this pic]

Answer (score 0):

simply write logic how can you get key value dynamically instant of putting some constant to get that value.
Find code below to get key using that logic.

```
 NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.section+1];
 NSString *text  = [[[[dic objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"h1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to slightly modify the JSON structure, to easily work with tableview section designs.

Like, **`{
values:[{"section1":[
{"Row1 or some constant":}]}]}`**
by this way, you can read the data easily. Try to make sections in an array and inside separate array for all the rows.

**FYI**: Some problem with code formatting. I don't know how to resolve.